# WooCommerce/Wordpress/JS: Get data from post type then send that to JS then seperate that into inputs

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

Im currently trying to assemble a plugin for my client that allows them to pull a list of address from a custom-post-type then select which one they would like to ship to then add that to woocommerce's shipping fields, and also make it work with multiple shipping addresses.

I've attached my code below, i've hit a road block when it comes to getting the info into from PHP to the JS and breaking it down to output to the proper fields and output in HTML.

```
<?php
    if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_MultiAddress' ) ) {

    /**
     * Localisation
     **/
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'WC_MultiAddress', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/' );

    class WC_MultiAddress {
        public function __construct() {
            // called only after woocommerce has finished loading
            add_action( 'woocommerce_init', array( &$this, 'woocommerce_loaded' ) );

            // called after all plugins have loaded
            add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( &$this, 'plugins_loaded' ) );

            // called just before the woocommerce template functions are included
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'include_template_functions' ), 20 );

            // indicates the user is in the right page
            if(is_page('checkout')){

                add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
                // Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
                function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
                        unset($fields['address']['address_1']);
                    unset($fields['address']['address_2']);

                     return $fields;
                }
                function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
                         $fields['shipping']['shipping_address'] = array(
                            'label'     => __('Shipping Address', 'woocommerce'),
                        'placeholder'   => _x('Add Full Street Address Here', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
                        'required'  => true,
                        'class'     => array('form-control'),
                        'clear'     => true
                         );

                         return $fields;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Display field value on the order edit page
                     */

                    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

                    function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
                        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Shipping Address').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_address', true ) . '</p>';
                    }
                    // indicates we are being served over ssl
                    if ( is_ssl() ) {
                        $shippings = array();
                        $args = array('post-type'=>'addressbook');
                        $query = New WP_Query($args);
                        if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();

                            $temp = array();
                            $temp['id'] = get_the_id();
                            $temp['fname'] = the_field('fname');
                            $temp['lname'] = the_field('lname');
                            $temp['email'] = the_field('email');
                            $temp['company'] = the_field('company');
                            $temp['addr1'] = the_field('address_line_1');
                            $temp['addr2'] = the_field('address_line_2');
                            $temp['city'] = the_field('city');
                            $temp['state'] = the_field('state');
                            $temp['zip'] = the_field('zip');
                            $shipping[] = $temp;

                        endwhile;endif;wp_reset_postdata();?>

                        <select id="address-select" class="form-control">
                            <?php foreach($shippings as $shipping){
                                extract($shipping);?>

                                <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words($fname, 1) . $lname . ' ' . $company . ' ' . $addr1 . ' ' . $city . ' ' . $state;?></option>

                                <?php
                            }
                        </select>
                        <Script>
                            $("#address-select").on("change", function(){
                                //Code here
                            })
                        </Script>
                        <?php





                        }

                    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_edit_checkout_fields' );

                        function custom_edit_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
                            // Change all attributes on a field
                            $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = array(
                                'label'     => __('Shipping Address', 'woocommerce'),
                                'placeholder'   => _x('123 Main St', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
                                'required'  => true,
                                'class'     => array('form-control'),
                                'clear'     => true,
                                'value'         => $addr1
                            );

                             return $fields;
                        }
                }



            // take care of anything else that needs to be done immediately upon plugin instantiation, here in the constructor
        }

        /**
         * Take care of anything that needs woocommerce to be loaded.
         * For instance, if you need access to the $woocommerce global
         */
        public function woocommerce_loaded() {
            // ...
        }

        /**
         * Take care of anything that needs all plugins to be loaded
         */
        public function plugins_loaded() {
            // ...
        }

        /**
         * Override any of the template functions from woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php
         * with our own template functions file
         */
        public function include_template_functions() {
            include( 'woocommerce-template.php' );
        }
    }

    // finally instantiate our plugin class and add it to the set of globals
    $GLOBALS['WC_MultiAddress'] = new WC_MultiAddress();
}
```

}

Comment: The `add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_edit_checkout_fields' );` and its relevant function should not be in the `if (is_page('checkout'))` conditional check.  The filter should be implemented the same way you are implementing the `add_action`.  Sorting the filter will output your new shipping field in checkout. And can you please explain why are you doing the `if(is_admin())` conditional check? Do you want the select with addresses render in the admin area or front-end? Because the `is_page('checkout')` and 'is_admin()` are a bit conflicting

Comment: Okay, I see that mistake and fixed it, my end goal is to have the user be able to pull a shipping account from a <select> and then have that broken down into the shipping fields, doing this with PHP and JS seemed like the best option. I know how to get data from the post type to PHP and from JS to HTML but it's that middle part getting it from PHP to JS that Im stuck on @OmarTanti